# if $f\in C(\mathbb{\overline{D}})$ and $\forall z\in\partial\mathbb{D}.f(z)=z$ then $\exists z\in\mathbb{D}.f(z)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, winding-number

if $f\in C(\mathbb{\overline{D}})$ and $\forall z\in\partial\mathbb{D}.f(z)=z$ then $\exists z\in\mathbb{D}.f(z)=0$

**f is not analytical only Continuous .**

**solve with complex analysis tools**

I thought looking at Winding  numbers , but I reached a deadend.

Comment: You added the sentence "**solve with complex analysis tools**" after my answer. No problem, someone may answer with complex analysis tools.

Comment: @Mathlover sorry, I tagged complex analysis, I thought it is enough, no need to down vote.

Comment: Sorry, I stopped downvoting(but I ignore). Maybe someone else. Let me give you an upvote. Are you happy now? Maybe I will put my answer in the comment section after someone post a solution just **only** using the complex analysis tools.

Comment: Suppose $f$ never vanishes on $\Bbb D$, then $r:=\frac{f}{|f|}$ is a retarction from $\Bbb D\to \Bbb S^1$, i.e. $r:\Bbb D^2\to\Bbb S^1$ is continuous and $r(z)=z$ for all $z\in \Bbb S^1$. Now, denoting the inclusion $i:\Bbb S^1\hookrightarrow \Bbb D$ we have $r\circ i=\text{Id}_{\Bbb S^1}$. Hence, using functoriality at the level of fundamental group the composition map $$\pi_1(\Bbb S^1)\xrightarrow{i_*}\pi_1(\Bbb D)\xrightarrow{r_*}\pi_1(\Bbb S^1)\text{ is same as }\text{Id}_{\pi_1(\Bbb S^1)}.$$

Comment: But, $\pi_1(\Bbb S^1)=\Bbb Z$ and $\pi_1(\Bbb D)$ is the trivial group as $\Bbb D$ is contractible. Hence, we reach to a contradiction.

Comment: Is the homotopy invariance of the winding number considered a "complex analysis tool"?

Comment: @Caffeine of course, if you can prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ never vanishes. Then $\gamma(s,t):=f(se^{it})$ is a homotopy equivalence between the constant curve $f(0)$
and the circle in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. This, however, is impossible: the winding number around zero of the two curves is different and we know it is homotopically invariant.

(The fact that the winding number is homotopically invariant follows from Cauchy's integral theorem)

Comment: what is s? why you assumed that the zero is in z=0?

Comment: I didn't assume that the zero is in $z=0$. $s$ is the parameter of the homotopy

Comment: so we'll get contradiction in the winding number? right?

Comment: Yes: the winding number of the constant curve is $0$, obviously, while that of the circle is $1$